# Using BeautifulSoup to find multiple elements with the same CSS Class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup's find_all() to search for elements that have the tag, "div" and the class, "wisbb_name". The HTML I'm scraping is from, http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/scores. My end goal is to take the names of all the pitchers that are starting for the day according to that website. The HTML of a pitchers name is below

`<div class="wisbb_name">M. Fiers</div>`

All pitchers HTML code has the same class just different text associated with it. I already use the line of code below to take all the results from find_all() and get the text associated with it.

```
for el in soup.find():
print(el.get_text())
```

That works fine the problem is find_all() isn't finding the elements I want it to find, no matter how much I alter the parameters. According to BeautifulSoup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all), the line of code below should find the element that has class, "wisbb_name" and the tag, "div".

```
variable = soup.find_all("div", class_="wisbb_name")
print(variable)
```

Upon printing variable, I just get an empty list. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way in python or I need to learn more about how HTML works. I have the latest version of BeautifulSoup and I'm using Python 3.6.2. My current full code is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("url from top because I can't use 3 links")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
for el in soup.find_all("div", class_="wisbb_name"):
    print(el.get_text())
```

Comment: I couldn't find `wisbb_name` class in the URL you provided.  Are you sure that's the right URL?

Comment: If you go to http://http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/scores, right click in chrome, then click inspect, then click the cursor icon in the top left of the new menu that opened. This should make it so when you click on a part of the website it selects the element in the inspect menu. Now just click a pitcher's name and it will take you to the element I am talking about.

Comment: To clarify, make sure to look at games that haven't started yet. It looks like the website doesn't display the current pitcher during live games. Just keep scrolling down till you see future games that are displaying the probable pitcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is rendered with JavaScript.
First render the page with [dryscrape](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

```
import bs4 as bs
import dryscrape

url = ("http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/scores")
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(url)
dsire_get = session.body()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(dsire_get,'lxml')
for el in soup.find_all("div", class_="wisbb_name"):
    print(el.get_text())
```

Outputs:

```
A. Sanchez
E. Santana
J. Shields
I. Kennedy
T. Williams
J. Hoffman
M. Scherzer
Z. Godley
C. Sale
R. Nolasco
C. Sabathia
A. Moore
J. García
A. Wood
T. Cahill
J. Samardzija
```

Or use selenium...
First install it:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Then get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver  
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ("http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/scores")
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
for el in soup.find_all("div", class_="wisbb_name"):
    print(el.get_text())
```

Or PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *  
from PyQt5.QtCore import *  
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *  
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import bs4 as bs
import sys

class Render(QWebPage):  
    def __init__(self, url):  
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        QWebPage.__init__(self)  
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
        self.app.exec_()  

    def _loadFinished(self, result):  
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
        self.app.quit()  

url = "http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/scores" 
r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(result,'lxml')
for el in soup.find_all("div", class_="wisbb_name"):
    print(el.get_text())
```